# Is there a way to remap the Logitech iTouch buttons on modern versions of Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-keyboard

I am using a Logitech Internet Navigator Keyboard (circa 2001 I believe, and have no intention of replacing it) and Windows 8.1. It has 8 'iTouch' keys, [E-Mail, Messenger, Webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjQw7.jpg) on the left, and [iTouch, Search, Shopping, Favourites and My Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqN4O.jpg) on the right. E-mail opens my default mail app, Search works with the Windows 8.1 shell, Favourites opens the favourites menu when in a browser and My Home opens a web browser.

On my Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) computer with the same keyboard, I can remap all of these keys to custom actions, launching apps, ejecting CDs etc. All the keys work out of the box.

But on my Windows 8.1 laptop, I can't find a way to remap the keys. I tried the Logitech iTouch software from their website, but it would not install ,[saying that my operating system was not compatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umndA.png). I tried changing the string at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Product Name` from `Windows 8.1` to `Microsoft Windows XP`, but the installer still would not start.

I used SharpKeys to try and capture the keycodes of the keys, but only the Mail and My Home keys were detected, [with the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFi2h.png) of `00_100`. AutoHotkey had a similar result, [the Mail, Search, Favourites and the Home key were detected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ToRV.png) None of the other keys were.

Is there a way to map any of the other keys to custom commands, such as setting the 'Shopping' key to open a specific website?
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you installed the Logitech software that came with it by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound it came with a CD of Logitech iTouch, I think 2.0, I tried both that version and the latest version from Logitech website which is 2.22; neither version would install and gave me the ‘incompatible with your operating system’ error